# Unsubscribe scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits.

Tags: redis

We're seeing error similar to the following on our redis servers since we migrated our web server (redis client) from Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 2012 R2

> [2455] 27 Jun 18:15:18.029 # Client addr=192.168.33.200:62653 fd=86
>   name=WEB6 age=79940 idle=191 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=2 multi=-1 qbuf=0
>   qbuf-free=0 obl=16338 oll=443 omem=12395832 events=rw cmd=unsubscribe
>   scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits.

Seems like we're triggering some sort of limit: http://redis.io/topics/clients#output-buffers-limits

Reading the above documentation indicates that normal clients have a default limit of 0, that means, no limit at all. Pub/Sub clients have a default hard limit of 32 megabytes and a soft limit of 8 megabytes per 60 seconds.

I'm not positive if we're using normal clients or pub/sub. I think the former but if that's the case I'm not sure why we're getting this error. How can I troubleshoot this more?